# Google Spreadsheet ? How can Icount a cell if it has any text if another cell has a specific value

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Google Spreadsheets and I am trying to count a range of cells if they contain a value If in a different range of cell contain a specific value.

Comment: this "=COUNTA(--(E2:E285="C")+A2:A285)"

Comment: Sample input data and expected output usually clarifies things better than just words

Comment: I am not sure how I can simplify my question. I have 2 columns 1 column (column A) can have multiple values in it (i.e A,B,C,D) the other column (column B) can have any value in it or no value at all. I need for example 1 cell to calculate any cell with the value of "A" in column A counted if the corresponding cell in column B has a value.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may want is something of this kind:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"A",B:B,"<>")
```

though please [see](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-spreadsheet/info).